# Agrupar producto por usuario MySQL

Tags: mysql

lo que quiero hacer es el query ya que estoy haciendo un filtro y quiero que la columna muestre el producto en el grid agrupado por usuario.
no se mucho de querys a ese nivel me podrian orientar
lo que tengo no es mucho

```
$detalleQuery="SELECT p.productos join order o on o.orders";
```

se que esta muy mal, agradeceria ayuda.

imagen ilustrativa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo me falta el query, de ante mano gracias

Tabla:Orders:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla:usersoperacion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías agregar por favor la estructura de tus 2 tablas involucradas? para tener una idea mas correcta de tu pregunta, aunque te adelanto es con `group by`

Comment: @element imagine que era con eso, pero desconozco como se usa para serte sincero, busco las tablas y edito de inmediato solo se que es producto y que lo agrupe con la tabla ordens donde estan las ordenes que vendio X usuario

Comment: y el manual de mysql? viste lo de group by ahi?

Comment: Igual para esta clase d epreguntas, necesitas poner tambien un ejemplo de datos de entrada, y salida esperada

Comment: Ya edite, la salida que espero es como la primera imagen donde el usuario del rol este ligada a los productos que vendio

Comment: y donde esta ese rol? y el nombre del producto? y que es lo que queres agrupar? tene en cuenta que no vemos tus tablas ni las entendemos con solo ver los nombres. y tu ejemplo, no tiene nada que ver con los datos que mostras